Android Activity: launch network task when data received from ViewModel
In an Android Views App with kotlin coroutines and ViewModel collecting data from a DataStore repository, I need to connect to a Bluetooth device when these data are received.   What I have done:
SettingsViewModel
@HiltViewModel
class SettingsViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val myRepository: MyRepository
) : ViewModel() {

    val setting1State : StateFlow<String> = myRepository.getSetting1().stateIn(
        viewModelScope,
        SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5000),
        ""
    )
    val setting2State : StateFlow<String> = myRepository.getSetting2().stateIn(
        viewModelScope,
        SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5000),
        ""
    )
}   

MainActivity
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val settingsViewModel: SettingsViewModel by viewModels()
    private var setting1 = ""
    private var setting2 = ""
    val socket : BluetoothSocket? by lazy (LazyThreadSafetyMode.NONE) {
        ...
    }

    onSettingsReceived() {
        if (setting1 != "" && setting2 != "") {
            lifecycleScope.launch (Dispatchers.IO) {
                ...
                socket.connect()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
                launch {
                    settingsViewModel.setting1State.collect {
                        setting1 = it
                        onSettingsReceived()
                    }
                }
                launch {
                    settingsViewModel.setting2State.collect {
                        setting2 = it
                        onSettingsReceived()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

This solution works most of the times, however it's ugly, and often the socket.connect() statement is executed twice in a very short timeframe, hence I don't think it's good. Also, I have unexplained disconnections, and I want to be sure this is not the root cause.
Any ideas on how to improve this?

Why is an activity directly doing Bluetooth communications? Would it be better for the Bluetooth communications to reside elsewhere (viewmodel or a singleton manager)?

@CommonsWare I think the reason is simply: my inexperience. Surely I can try moving it somewhere else. Being a BT printer that needs to print when the app receives an intent from outside (an order confirmation from another application), what would you suggest?

That depends on what is supposed to happen if the user leaves that activity before the printing is complete. If the answer is "we abandon the printing", then I would have the communications be in the viewmodel, where you stop the printing work in onCleared(). If the answer is "we need to complete the printing", then the printing needs to reside in some singleton, and you may need to consider a foreground service to ensure your process lives long enough to complete the printing operation. Keep the activity's scope to be purely UI concerns.
